# Bulk convert unix time to date in Matlab

Tags: matlab, modeling, unix-timestamp, graphing

I am trying to plot a cumulative graph of infected hosts for an assignment. (Code Red, if that helps! Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I have gotten the data from caida.org, but they are all in unix time. What I am trying to do is to bulk convert all of the unix time cells into dates, is that possible in Matlab?
I tried searching around, both with google and matlab's forum, but the closest I was able to find was some premade scripts that converts the time one by one. (Here's the link to one of them. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32187-unix-time-to-matlab-time-converter)

If I'm in the wrong direction, or if there are other software that are meant for plotting the type of graphs I'm trying to plot, please tell!

Thanks!

Comment: Won't it work if you input the unix times as a column vector, something like this - `unixtime([1095379198;1095379199])`? Then wrap it with `datestr`?